# Angular Http Interceptor can't get user token with localStorage to add to header

Tags: angular, token

This is my first time in coding an Interceptor in my angular client.
I followed a few articles on google to add HttpInteceptor. I called a web api and got the token. I verified with console logging that the token was received and added it my localstorage. Here is my angular service code:

```
loginUser(user) : Observable<boolean> {
      var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded','No-Auth':'True' });
  return  this.http
        .post('http://localhost:55009/api/login', user )
        .map((data: any) => {
          this.token = data.token.token;
            localStorage.setItem('userToken', data.token.token);
            this.errorMessage = data.token.error;
console.log('token ===> ' + data.token.token);
console.log('isTokenValid ===> ' + this.isTokenValid());

console.log('errorMessage ===> ' + this.errorMessage);


                  return this.isTokenValid();
                })
    //  .map((response:any) => response.json())
     .catch(this.handleError);
              }
```

When I clicked on a different route/menu, I stepped thru the code in the interceptor.ts. When the code call localStorage.getItem and the login.getToken but both return empty strings. I checked the online sample tutorial and did not see anything different in my code:

```
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
 public userToken: string;

    constructor(private router: Router, public login: LoginService) { }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

this.userToken =  this.login.getToken();

        if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') == "True")
            return next.handle(req.clone());

        if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
            const clonedreq = req.clone({
                headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('userToken'))
            });
            return next.handle(clonedreq)
                .do(
                succ => { },
                err => {
                    if (err.status === 401)
                        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
                }
                );
        }
        else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It was strange. In the angular service, I was able to get the token and set it with LocalStorage. However, the component, the LocalStorage was returning null. I moved the LocalStorage.setItem from the service to component and I can see the value on Chrome dev tool now.

Answer (score 0):

You have to subscribe your `http` request.

```
.map((response:any) => response.json())
.subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```

Comment: In my login component call, I did subscribe. Is there other code? this.loginService.loginUser(this.user).subscribe((data : any)=>{
   


      document.getElementById("cancelBtn").click();
    },

Answer (score 0):

First verify that the token is still in your local storage. You can do this on Chrome by:

- Go to the dev tools
- Click on on the 'Application' tab
- Click on 'Local Storage' on the left nav bar
- Find your site name under Local Storage and click on it

That will tell you if the token is still present in local storage. If yes, then I suggest you set a breakpoint in your interceptor code to confirm that it's correctly running when the route is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in loginUser method:

```
this.token = data;
localStorage.setItem('userToken', this.token.token);
```

instead:

```
this.token = data.token.token;
localStorage.setItem('userToken', data.token.token);
```